# Acumatica - Import Scenario (Screen SM206036) error "CS Error #33 cannot generate next number for sequence

Tags: erp, acumatica

During the Acumatica ERP Import Scenario (ScreenId=SM206036) process, I am getting a "CS Error #33: Cannot generate the next number for the sequence because it is expired. CS Error #33: Cannot generate the next number for the sequence because it is expired.”

Has anyone seen this error before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have a numbering sequence is not configured for the screen where you import data to.

Simplest way to validate it is to open the screen itself and try to enter the data manually.

Answer (score 0):

For which screen do you want to make import? You should check numbering sequence settings for that screen. Looks like generating new id's for that screen doesn't fit to rules of date.

Answer (score -1):

I think the last number maybe reach to the maximum value in the setting! Please review it setting and check with Mike suggestion!